Mapbox Geocoder on Safari
The following snippet works perfectly on Chrome displaying a search bar to autofill address results. Unfortunately Safari (17.5 in my case) does not recognize .on method on mapboxGeocoder object. Is there a solution ? (Working in a Rails 7 app using Stimulus controller)


  initMapboxAutofill() {

    mapboxgl.accessToken = window.mapboxAccessToken;

    this.mapboxGeocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({
      accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
      mapboxgl: mapboxgl,
      marker: false,
      autocomplete: true,
      placeholder: 'Search for an address',
    });

    if (this.hasGeocoderAutocompleteTarget) {
      this.geocoderAutocompleteTarget.appendChild(this.mapboxGeocoder.onAdd());

      if (typeof this.mapboxGeocoder.on === 'function') {
        this.mapboxGeocoder.on('result', (event) => {
          const { geometry } = event.result;
          this.populateAddressFields(event);
      
          const coordinates = geometry.coordinates;
          this.displayStaticMap(coordinates);
        });
      } else {
        console.error('Mapbox Geocoder "on" method is not available.'); //Safari flow
      }
    } else {
      this.initStaticMapForExistingHome();
    }
  }





    <script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/plugins/mapbox-gl-geocoder/v5.0.0/mapbox-gl-geocoder.min.js"></script>
    <script id="search-js" defer src="https://api.mapbox.com/search-js/v1.0.0-beta.21/web.js"></script>
    <script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v3.5.1/mapbox-gl.js"></script>




Removing


    <script id="search-js" defer src="https://api.mapbox.com/search-js/v1.0.0-beta.21/web.js"></script>



did the trick in my situation. It's a legacy import not used in my app that seems to conflict with geocoder module on Safari for some reasons.
